# img.ly PhotoeditorSDK Not working on Next.js built project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, photoeditorsdk

I'm building the Next.js project and making the app the same as React.js. It's working well in debugging mode, but after building the app, it's showing this error on:

```js
import { PhotoEditorSDKUI, Tool, UIEvent } from 'photoeditorsdk';
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/photoeditorsdk

> IMG.LY Product: PE.SDK   Platform: Web   Web Wrapper: React JS SDK
> Version: 5.14.0 Devices OS: Win 10
>
> error output:   467-40c81e1cf973201c8664.js:1 ReferenceError: Fo is
> not defined at Module.78424 (203-ccd5608d077546a0d990.js:305) at n
> (webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1) at Object.33467
> (467-40c81e1cf973201c8664.js:1) at n
> (webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1) at Object.63862
> (467-40c81e1cf973201c8664.js:1) at n
> (webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1) at Module.48624
> (index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1) at n
> (webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1) at index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1
> at main-5880b1d57202aca5456a.js:1 33467 @
> 467-40c81e1cf973201c8664.js:1 n @ webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1
> 63862 @ 467-40c81e1cf973201c8664.js:1 n @
> webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1 48624 @
> index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1 n @ webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1
> (anonymous) @ index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1 (anonymous) @
> main-5880b1d57202aca5456a.js:1 Promise.then (async) onEntrypoint @
> main-5880b1d57202aca5456a.js:1 Y @ main-5880b1d57202aca5456a.js:1
> 27950 @ index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1 n @
> webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1 (anonymous) @
> index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1 n.O @
> webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1 (anonymous) @
> index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1 t @ webpack-b19e12b5ec856c13b0c3.js:1
> (anonymous) @ index-597622c10c04ead06da2.js:1

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue with various build environments. I worked around it by installing version 5.6.1 of photoeditorsdk `npm install photoeditorsdk@5.6.1`

This isn't a proper solution but I had no other options, PESDK helpdesk couldn't offer me a solution.

Comment: yes, I tried with photoeditorsdk@5.8.2, it's working also.

Comment: but That's not working from 5.8.3 to 5.14.0(latest)

Comment: You could also try loading the cjs build: import { PhotoEditorSDKUI, Tool, UIEvent } from 'photoeditorsdk/cjs';

Comment: I tried with the cjs build, It's can build but photoeditor SDK not working also. – 
Here is the error log:
3d0b6d5c-7e0ad40b9a6a3e7553cf.js:2384 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Super constructor null of anonymous class is not a constructor
    at new <anonymous> (3d0b6d5c-7e0ad40b9a6a3e7553cf.js:2384)
    at 3d0b6d5c-7e0ad40b9a6a3e7553cf.js:2384
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

Comment: at Object.init (3d0b6d5c-7e0ad40b9a6a3e7553cf.js:2384)
    at Object.init (3d0b6d5c-7e0ad40b9a6a3e7553cf.js:2384)
    at 536-3b5905ac38fb4747fed0.js:1
    at l (main-267348f162b37be6fbc0.js:1)
    at Generator._invoke (main-267348f162b37be6fbc0.js:1)
    at Generator.next (main-267348f162b37be6fbc0.js:1)
    at r (_app-3b9b4caba2224f8147fe.js:1)

Comment: If anyone have solution, Please let me know.